# Batch conversion of epoch to datetime in TQL query

Tags: t-sql

Converting epoch time to SQL datetime format. I am trying to convert the 35 000 records received from another table (other db) with epoch timestemp to a new table with SQL datetime format. Also I will need to have this updated on a daily basis so one time conversion is good but I am also open to other suggestions.

I never worked with epoch and I am not sure how to go about it.

Also later on I want to use it in SSRS with correct datetime so I am not sure should I convert it before the transfer to new table or to do it in SSRS?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? Is it simply how to convert eposh to a Date and Time data type?

Comment: Yes, I need to convert but many records from one table or use it in view or sp_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that the epoch timestamp you have is in *seconds*:

```
DATEADD(SECOND, epoch_col, '19700101')
```

This will add the epoch seconds to the start of '*epoch time*' (01-01-1970 00:00:00) and give you a `DATETIME`.

Example with output:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1571994774, '19700101')

2019-10-25 09:12:54.000
```

If you have an epoch timestamp in *milliseconds* just use this variation:

```
DATEADD(MILLISECOND, epoch_col, '19700101')
```

In terms of your other question about when to convert the value;  My view is that it would be preferable to store the value in a `DATETIME` column at point of insertion rather than storing the epoch value and converting it upon use.

This is just an opinion though and not a recommendation.

Comment: Ok thanks but what if I have a 35 000 records. this is only one '19700101'.

Comment: @Toni Yes indeed, so just include it in your `UPDATE` statement.  I would have thought the use of it was clear from the answer

Comment: Thanks Martin, only thing is how to use it in the update statement when creating a view or sp? Lets say the field name is EPdate.

Comment: Martin does show you in their last example, @Toni , how to replace a integer literal with a column name.

Comment: You can't use an `UPDATE` in a view, @Toni . A `VIEW` is simply a pre-written `SELECT` statement. If cannot perform any DML operations

Comment: Great, it works like a charm. I can build on it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just got one more thing. I realized I am on UTC +3. Hot do I do this in the query.