# Epoch timestamp converted to datetime but how to sort records later on

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got my answer from Martin on [how to convert epoch to date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555391/batch-conversion-of-epoch-to-datetime-in-tql-query) but now I am facing another issue. How to do I filter records that are only entered today or some other date?

I created view with DATEADD(SECOND, Timing, '19700101') and want to filter out records.

```
select * from [dbo].[vw_records]
where Timing like '%23-10-2019%'
```

This way I am not able to query datetime based on that view. So as far the conversion it is good solution but for querying records not too good.

On other hand, maybe it is better to convert it in the table and then query results. hm...

Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rows from today, then use inclusive Date logic:

```
SELECT {Columns list}
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateColumn >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND DATECOLUMN < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()));
```

For today, this'll return all rows on or after `2019-10-28T00:00:00:00.000` and **before** (but not including) `2019-10-29T00:00:00:00.000`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `DATE > 2019-10-27` will work and be easier (for records newer than yesterday in this example, where a keeps the date data in this format)

Comment: OP has  `datetime` values, @kakigadol , and `2019-10-27T00:00:01` isn't today but **is** `> 2019-10-27`. That would return the wrong rows.

Comment: I'm using datetime values in my DB and I almost always use a where clause similar to what I wrote in order to get results from specific dates..

Comment: So why would you want rows on or after `2017-10-27T00:00:00.003` when you want rows for **today** @kakigadol ?

Comment: Gave it as an example.. for today's rows he could use
 ```SELECT {Columns list} FROM Table WHERE data > '2019-10-28'```
no need for conversion or any other function, and just checked with a production database and it works

Comment: I disagree again @kakigadol , that code does not work; it only returns 2 rows in this small example, but 1 is wrong (it's on the 29th) and one for the 28th is missing. Notice, however, that my solution returns the correct rows: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38486d6ad0fca56960cb47cdaec5d1a1)

Comment: Yes the solution from Lamu works great...But do you think it would be better to convert epoch to datetime and then querying it? Or how can I query epoch time directly from the table?

Comment: Larnu- I might have learned something new :), I'll dig into it in order to find out why it worked with my case and not in your example
Toni- it depends on your case, I would suggest use the same type everywhere in your project, either epoch or datetime everywhere.
about your question of how to query epoch, you can convert the datetime into epoch within the query in order to make it readable

Comment: Personally, I think it would be better to store the datetime value, @Toni . That could be with a `PERSISTED` Computer column or switching from Epoch to a `datetime2`. Then you can always use datetime logic to query the values; which is far easier to understand.

Comment: The only possible problem with datetime is time zones as they are different all over the world, and epoch doesn't care about it..
Besides that I would use datetime too

Comment: In an environment where timezones factor in, then either using UTC throughout the application or using `datetimeoffset` and storing the timezone is the solution, @kakigadol . Which one you use can entirely depend on preferences, but there are some scenarios where knowing the timezone is important as well. If the need to know the timezone *might* ever be a requirement, then `datetimeoffset` should be the preferred solution.

Comment: Yes thanks all, now I got the results in a view and I can filter all the records. Now because of the 3h time difference I will have to use DATEADD to make up to this 3 h in every new query. Or if there is any other way. I see the Persisted has to be used in the column in a table but this is a table which I don't want to mess with since it has connection. Only I can work on are views, sp etc..